# POST data from one page to another

Tags: java, php, post, security

I am trying to implement some data flow as follows

```
 ______________               _____________                    _____________
| myecom.com   |  submit     | myecom.com  |  add additional  | payment.com |
| product.html |------------>| process.php |----------------->|   pay.php   |
|   myform     |  form data  |             |  data & submit   |             |
 --------------               -------------                    -------------
                                                                     |
                      ______________                                 |
                     |  myecom.com  |<--------------------------------
                     | receiver.php |      success or failure info
                      --------------
```

1. An ecommerce site receive some info from user
2. Submit the info to an internal processor
3. The internal processor processes the data
4. The processed data along with some additional data is submitted to an external processor
5. The external processor sends back some success/failure report

My goal is to perform step 4 without informing the user what data is being submitted to external processor. In another word, I want to POST some data to the external processor from the internal processor.

FYI, simply cURL will not do as it does not redirect. The page must redirect to payment.com/pay.php. Also, it need to to be PHP specific, any technology like Java, etc. will do. I am considering storing the data in session using cURL and then javascript redirect. But is there any other ways?

Thanks a lot for your time
Khalid

Comment: Why not *only* store them inside a PHP Session? Thereby all values will be stored no matter how often you do a redirect. Hand data by `$_POST` from `product.html` to `process.php` should be suitable

Comment: redirects wont preserve session data as both servers will be different. You have to carry the data in url as key value parameters or possibly in form of POST data. or check for other options live SOAP calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. One of my friend suggested to bypass `process.php` and submit directly to `payment.com` using encrypted (salted by client's password or words that only known by server and API client, not user) hidden fields in `product.html`. In that case, will the server and client code (PHP or ASP or Java) be able to implement same encryption method?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it like this instead?

```
 ______________               _____________                       _____________
| myecom.com   | (1) submit  | myecom.com  | (2) add additional  | payment.com |
| product.html |------------>| process.php |-------------------->|   pay.php   |
|   myform     |  form data  |             |  data & submit      |             |
--------------               -------------                        -------------
                                  |    ^                               |
                                  |    |                               |
                     (4) redirect |    ---------------------------------
                                  |       (3) success or failure info
                                  v
                             ______________ 
                            |  myecom.com  |
                            | receiver.php |      
                             --------------
```

**Explanation:** Your internal processor sends the user data plus the additional data to the external processor. Since it's your server that makes the POST request to the external processor, the user never sees the request and thus cannot see the data that is being sent.

I'm not a PHP programmer, but a quick Google query on "PHP post request" revealed these two links, see if they help you:

[How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

[Three Ways to Make a POST Request from PHP](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/three-ways-to-make-a-post-request-from-php)